# Relation in YII with not "ID" as primary key

Tags: yii

I'm having a model Anketa which has `user_id` as a primary key, not just `id`.
And I want to create a HAS_ONE relation for it so i code this:

```
function relations()
{
return array(
...
'last_experience' => array(
    self::HAS_ONE, 'Experience', 'user_id',
    'condition' => '
        `signoff` = (
        SELECT MAX( `signoff` )
        FROM `experience` AS t2
        WHERE t2.user_id = last_experience.user_id )
    ',
),  
);
}
```

But when I try to get this property I get *"Property "Anketa.id" is not defined."* error.

I found some code in CActiveFinder.php file that does the following:

```
if($this->relation instanceof CBelongsToRelation)
{
    if(is_int($i))
    {
        if(isset($parent->_table->foreignKeys[$fk]))  // FK defined
            $pk=$parent->_table->foreignKeys[$fk][1];
        else if(is_array($this->_table->primaryKey)) // composite PK
            $pk=$this->_table->primaryKey[$i];
        else
            $pk=$this->_table->primaryKey;
    }
    $params[$pk]=$record->$fk;
}
```

This block returns `id` for some reason instead of `user_id`. I don't know if it's a  bug, because other relations work fine, but they're just not as complicated as this one.

Why does it happen? How can I fix this?

Thank you!

Comment: you will need to add 'on' after 'condition' in the relation to tell the model which fields should be compared.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to leave the PK field empty and use the 'on' condition override.

```
function relations()
{
    return array(
        'last_experience' => array(
            self::HAS_ONE,
            'Experience',
            '',
            'on' => 'user_id=last_experience.user_id'
        ),
    );
}
```